# Setting up a server farm with few RPi

Tags: server

I want to set up a server farm with few Raspberry Pis (at least two).

I found this amazing tutorial - http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html

Although there is detail about the load balancer, there isn't much about setting up the Pis...

I would like to know what do do with the Pis, I heard about few softwares like GlusterFS...

It would be awesome if someone could direct me what to do or send me a good tutorial that will help me with this task...

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Beware the pi is not very well suited to this because of the limited network throughput, unless it is just for experimental/educational purposes.  Like a bonsai tree farm, could be very interesting but has no commercial potential lumber wise.

Comment: @goldilocks: there's a bonsai shop near where I live that sells those little trees for $50-$1600 a piece. Now you've got me thinking if a "bonsai server farm" could be economically feasible in anyway...

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yes because how else would you build a million dollar tiny home?  Carpe diem -- "Boutique cloud services" could be an emerging market >_>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good article from reputable Make magazine at:

[Compact 4 Node Raspberry Pi Cluster](http://makezine.com/projects/build-a-compact-4-node-raspberry-pi-cluster/)

Step by step with diagrams, configuration and code

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent - sounds like a great project. Do you consider this post as an answer or useful response?

Comment: Maybe a bit of both...

Comment: Hah - ok - I was trying to be not so subtle about upvoting my answer or even markign it as an answer. But as an aside - I just read a great excerpt from a Pi hardware book about full setup and config of 4 Pis using Apache Spark with a code comparison of doiing pi (the number) calculation using Monte Carlo simulation. Cluster was 185 times faster

Comment: Wow, sounds amazing! I am planning to make a web server with raspberry pi s as workers and an old PC running Ubuntu as a load balancer. This idea is from an article/tutorial that I read about... But, I'm still 14 years old and I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Amazing - keep it up. You've got some great ideas